# How to select Label Encoded categorical variables for creating Dummies?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I'm working on a dataset in which categorical variables are already `LabelEncoded`. So, my question is, Do I convert all of them into dummy variables even though some of them have either 0 or 1 as a value?

Some variables have the values: (-1, 0, 1) and (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)

Dummies will give me binary values but I already have the binary values for some of the categorical features as I mentioned above. Is there any point in converting them into dummies?

Also, the categorical features I have are of `int64` type. Should I convert them into `object` type first and then create the dummies, or Should I just left them as `int64` and then create the dummies.

I'm currently making dummies using `get_dummies()` from pandas, Is it any different from `OneHotEncoder`? If so, then which one is preferable?

This is the head of the dataset:

```
 custid         region  townsize    gender  age agecat  birthmonth  ed  edcat   jobcat  ... owncd   ownpda  ownpc   ownipod owngame ownfax  news    response_01 response_02 response_03
 3964-QJWTRG-NPN    1   2.0         1       20  2       September   15  3           1   ...     0       0       0       1       1       0   0       0           1           0
 0648-AIPJSP-UVM    5   5.0         0       22  2       May         17  4           2   ...     1       1       1       1       1       1   1       0           0           0
 5195-TLUDJE-HVO    3   4.0         1       67  6       June        14  2           2   ...     1       0       0       0       0       0   1       0           0           0
 4459-VLPQUH-3OL    4   3.0         0       23  2       May         16  3           2   ...     1       0       1       1       1       0   1       1           0           0
 8158-SMTQFB-CNO    2   2.0         0       26  3       July        16  3           2   ...     1       0       1       0       1       0   0       0           1           0
```

I want to prepare this dataset for `LinearRegression` Model.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the end goal of this data preparation exercise  is an ML algo. So you need to look at your data from the prerequisites of that algo. In general, with most of the algos, you're fine if your data is numerically encoded, whatever the data preprocessing algo you use, `Label Encoder` or `One Hot Encoder`.

On a finer scale, which one is preferred will depend on the algo, your data, and amount of data at hand.

Anyway, the only way to say which one is better for your task and data -- [Label Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or [One Hot Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) (or [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) from pandas) -- is to run your algo through cross validation with different data preprocessing.

To add more considerations to your choice, some algos, e.g. `KNN` and `deep learning`, may demand data normalization.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I want to prepare this for LinearRegression Model.

Comment: Try either OHO or Label Encoder with your categorical features, run CV with your preferred metric, and see which one is better. My bet Label Encoder will perform better.

Comment: If your target algo is Linear Regression, you have one restriction: you need to have more cases in your data than features (your feature matrix should be in a "long" format). So, depending on your data, OHO may be out of choice based on this restriction (and amount of data).

Comment: Pretty much all the categorical variables are Label Encoded already in the dataset except for the 'birthmonth' and 'age' features and I'm gonna drop the 'custid'. Will only Label encoding be suffice to create the Linear Regression model? I was under the impression that the equations in my model might think one category has higher value than the other, since 0<1<2.  And yes, my target algo is indeed Linear Regression.

Comment: (1) Try encode `birthmonth` and `age` with either OHO or LabelEncoder and see which one is better (2) If you believe some features were wrongly encoded ("some category has higher value than the other, since 0<1<2") you may try re-encode them either through OHO or applying a dictionary to that column, that will re-cast them to proper values. In latter case, arranging the categories in the proper order (0,1,2,3,4, etc) is not enough. For OLS to properly interpret say "4" and "2", "4" must be 2 times bigger than "2".